# What's the constant coefficient of the Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm?

Tags: ds.algorithms, time-complexity

Every source I can find just says "too big to be practical."

Comment: I'm not sure anyone ever computed it. By the way, what constant are you looking for ? The constant for the number of multiplications ? Arithmetic operations ? Etc.

Comment: Arithmetic operations I suppose. Just to get some idea what the order of magnitude would be for CW and similar algorithms.

Comment: Someone has definitely computed an upper bound on the leading constant for the number of arithmetic ops, but I do not remember who (it was submitted  to a conference years ago) and I am not sure the writeup was ever made public... I will check. My recollection is that it was < 10^(500)...

Comment: @RyanWilliams No luck?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact answer, but here are some relevant quotes regarding fast matrix multiplication in general:

(This quote is about an earlier method with $O(N^{2.77})$ complexity. $m^{*}(3^s|F)$ is the number of scalar multiplications required to multiply two $3^s \times 3^s$ matrices, excluding multiplications involved in constructing linear combinations of matrix entries.)

> The last step is the crucial point with respect to all practical
> applications of the method. Of course, we can assume that $F$ is
> infinite and use Lemma 2.6, which gives the better bound $m^{*}(3^s|F) \leq (1 + 2s)21^s$, but even then the minimal value of $s$
> for which this becomes smaller than the trivial bound $27^s$ is $s = 14$,
> and $3^{14} = 4,782,969$. The same will apply for all other bounds given
> in this paper.

*Schönhage, A.*, [**Partial and total matrix multiplication**](https://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0210032), SIAM J. Comput. 10, 434-455 (1981).

> Actually, there are two groups of algorithms that support an exponent
> lower than Strassen’s value of 2.81. The first group consists of
> algorithms that use various advanced techniques and support exponents
> from 2.38 to 2.775. [...]
>
> If we restrict our study to the
> multiplication of $N \times N$ matrices for $N < 10^{20}$, the only competition
> for Strassen’s algorithm comes from a second group of algorithms.
> [...] These algorithms support exponents $\omega$ of about 2.775. Since the
> crossover value of $N$ for which such algorithms improve on Strassen’s
> is as low as 20, these algorithms are good candidates for being of
> practical value when compared to Strassen’s and classical algorithms
> for MM [matrix multiplication].

*Laderman, Julian; Pan, Victor; Sha, Xuan-He*, [**On practical algorithms for accelerated matrix multiplication**](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437959290393O/pdf?md5=a704930f7084a84b64a6007040d6253a&pid=1-s2.0-002437959290393O-main.pdf), Linear Algebra Appl. 162-164, 557-588 (1992).

> All known algorithms supporting matrix multiplication exponents below
> 2.7733, however, suffer from the curse of recursion: they involve very long recursive processes, whose each recursive step squares the input
> size, and so these algorithms supersede the classical matrix
> multiplication only for inputs of astronomical sizes, being far above
> the level of any imaginable practical interest. The design and the
> study of these algorithms was widely advertised and generously
> supported, but made no impact on real world computations for matrix
> multiplication or any other problem of Mathematics and Computational
> Mathematics. As of 2017 the record bound $\omega < 2.7734$ of [114] for
> feasible matrix multiplication of dimensions $n$ of at most 1 000 000
> 000 has remained unbeaten since 1982.

*Pan, Victor Ya.*, [**Fast matrix multiplication and its algebraic neighbourhood**](https://dx.doi.org/10.1070/SM8833), Sb. Math. 208, No. 11, 1661-1704 (2017); translation from Mat. Sb. 208, No. 11, 90-138 (2017).

So everything below $O(N^{\approx 2.8})$ is ***really*** impractical.

(*off-topic*) Actually, even Strassen's algorithm has little practical importance. It gives only $O((\mathrm{number\ of\ operations})^{0.023})$ increase in the maximum matrix size that you can afford given limited computational resources. For large-scale linear algebra, better options are available, such as preconditioned iterative linear solvers or Monte Carlo matrix multiplication.